# Half star rating in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rating

I am building an application where I have to use half star rating using angular Js. How can I create that?
Whenever user hover over the start It will show the half star and full star

Comment: you can try [`ui.bootstrap` rating](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#rating)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_star_rating.asp
Try this link which will be helpful

Comment: angularjs ui.bootstrap provide full star not half. As well as I want the value wherer user clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is HTML example:

```
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is CSS example:

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

Bring logic to it using *JavaScript* to each half-star and you are good to go.

[Source](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh)

Comment: Thanks for the help